# C++ vector<T> v, vector<T>*v, vector<T*> vec, which is the fastest (or the most efficient)?

Tags: c++, pointers, vector

A friend of mine told me that a vector of pointer(s) is more preferable than a normal vector, in terms of processing time.
In other words, the former (e.g. `vector<int> *i`) would be faster than the later (e.g. `vector<int> i`).

According to my friend, the reason is that ***memory allocation will be reduced by using this type of vectors*** (`vector<int> *i`).

However, I honestly don't understand why, because `vector<int> *i` would need twice as many memory addresses as `vector<int> i` (as long as both of those vectors contain the same number of elements.)

*For example, if `vector<int> *i` will point to 3 elements, there should be 4 memory address needed. One is for a pointer, the other are for integer variables.*

Also, I noticed that declaring a vector like `vector<int*> i` is valid too.

Here are 3 vectors.

```
vector<T> v1;
vector<T*> v2;
vector<T> *v3;
```

I guess `v1` is a vector which will contain only variables (not pointers) whose data type if `T`.

`v2` would contain pointers which will point to variables whose type is `T`.

`v3` would be a single pointer, which can point to one or multiple variables whose type is `T`.

So, which one do you think would be the fastest to access, and do you see any misunderstanding above?

I'd really appreciate if you would give any advice/suggestion.

Comment: `vector<int> *i` is not a vector of pointers to int, it's a pointer to a vector of ints.

Comment: "which is the fastest (or the most efficient)?" - it is **impossible** to tell without a very specific use case. Whowever asserts that "a vector of pointers is always preferable" talks complete nonsense.

Comment: A vector of objects may be better in some cases due to cache locality.  A vector of pointers may be better in some cases because the objects are expensive to copy.  A pointer to a vector doesn't really seem to belong with the other two.  As others have said, it will depend on your specific use case.

Comment: Thank you all. It seems I need to study the basics of vectors & pointers much more.

Comment: >Retired Ninja, `the objects are expensive to copy`. Yes I was concerned about this too.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a big misunderstanding here: You are comparing vectors with different semantics. It's like asking which is faster, a glass of water or a banana.

If you think about using a vector of pointers, `std::vector<T*>`, you need to be aware that you are using manual memory management. It might be faster in some use-cases, but it's also way more error prone. If your use-case is appropriate, you might consider `std::vector<std::shared_ptr<T>>` or `std::vector<std::unique_ptr<T>>` instead.

`std::vector<T>*` is something else entirely. You need to learn about the background of how, when and why to use plain pointers (hint: they are rarely used at all these days), smart pointers or simply no pointers and instead use the objects directly.

In terms of efficiency, even a normal `std::vector<T>` can nowadays be quite efficient due to move semantics. Google it and learn about it as well. Also, efficiency does not just come from the number of memory allocations, but also from the memory layout. This is where a `std::vector<T>` can often provide severe benefits over the alternatives.

And with everything which is about efficiency: Measure it! Without measuring, you will never really know what is better for your use-case. Start with the most obvious and correct code (that is to say: Avoid manual memory management), measure it, find the bottlenecks, only then remove them by possibly adding more complexity.

Comment: `Measure it! ` Alright! Thank you so much for your specific advice.